# Getting crash in JNI callback from C to Java

Tags: java, android, c, callback, java-native-interface

I am using a third party C native library which is calling callbacks to my JNI.

So in my JNI's C portion, I have a callback function `callback()` which i registered to the library while initialization. This is getting called by the library as a callback, no issues with that.

But once it enters the function `callback()` and when i try to call the java function in my upper layer, I get a crash.

Here's the function `callback()` snippets :

```
threadStatus = (*javaVM)->GetEnv(javaVM, (void **)&envCallBack, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,"threadStatus--------------- ", "%d",threadStatus); //threadStatus is -2 as I can see in logs

     if(threadStatus == JNI_EDETACHED)
     {

     res = (*javaVM)->AttachCurrentThread(javaVM,(void**)&envCallBack,NULL);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,"______________Getting JNI Env_________Race JNI", "%d",122333);

     if(res != JNI_OK)
             return;
     }
     else if (res == JNI_EVERSION) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,"______________JNI Version Not Supported________Race JNI", "%d",122333);
        }
```

then at the end of this function I am calling,

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,"______________CallMethod_________Race JNI", "%d",callMethod);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,"______________Parameter 1_________Race JNI", "%d",eventDataValue);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,"______________Parameter 2_________Race JNI", "%d",obj_callbackData);
    (*envCallBack)->CallVoidMethod(envCallBack, callbackObject, callMethod);
```

where I am getting the crash. Can anyone suggest what's the mistake I am doing? Am i attaching the thread correctly?

Here are the logs :

```
V/threadStatus--------------- ( 2021): -2
V/______________Getting JNI Env_________Race JNI( 2021): 122333
V/_______________Method Called_________Race JNI( 2021): 200000
V/_______________Before Method Called RaceCallBack_________Race JNI( 2021): 200000
V/______________CallMethod_________Race JNI( 2021): 1115468904
V/______________Parameter 1_________Race JNI( 2021): 0
V/______________Parameter 2_________Race JNI( 2021): 1080861840
W/dalvikvm( 2021): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception raised
W/dalvikvm( 2021):              in Ldalvik/system/NativeStart;.run ()V (CallVoidMethod)
W/dalvikvm( 2021): Pending exception is:
I/dalvikvm( 2021): Ljava/lang/CloneNotSupportedException;: Class doesn't implement Cloneable
I/dalvikvm( 2021):  at java.lang.Object.clone(Object.java:155)
I/dalvikvm( 2021):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 2021): "Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
I/dalvikvm( 2021):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x406ca3b0 self=0x1f6040
I/dalvikvm( 2021):   | sysTid=2057 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2214832
I/dalvikvm( 2021):   | schedstat=( 1783000 11852000 9 )
I/dalvikvm( 2021):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: You've got a pending `CloneNotSupportedException`. That's probably what you should start investigating.

Comment: @Michael : I did see that, but I am not able to figure out the reason as what is causing that exception?